# How to access my thermostat data through other nest developer account?

Tags: nest-api

I had instslled nest thermostat in my home (its really wonderful). I also created one nest devloper account om nest developers site. So i want to access (for ex. Deviceid or device name ) of my thermostat details through my nest developer account.  How i can achive this?

I also tried following steps. But its unsuccessful.

1. Sign up nest developer account.
2. Created a cloud application.
3. I got the product id,product secret and authorization code.
4. I added my nest thermostat account to in family account.
5. I got the token and called device_id API using the token. 
   But got the error as 401 unauthorized.

Please can some one help on this?

Comment: My recommendation is go to the nest forums and talk to other developers there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an access token, you should be able to retrieve all the device details using that access token.  See [API Read Examples](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-read-data) for examples on how to use the access token.

Also, when using [Family Accounts](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/family-accounts), keep in mind that only the structure owner can access the device information through the API.